# If you use a regular HTML <form> tag instead of the Spring <form:form> tag, how do you specify where it's submitted?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, forms

In the Spring docs, [the section on multipart support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html#mvc-multipart) has an example of specifying a multipart form as this:

```
<form method="post" action="upload.form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This doesn't use the Spring form tags which I am familiar with and instead submits the form to the `upload.form` action.

How does Spring know what `upload.form` means? Do you have to create a mapping for it and, if so, where is this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upload.form` is the URL of the HTTP POST request that is created by this form.  It will be relative to the URL of the view that generated the form in the first place, so if the form shown above is rendered by `/mysite/myapp/myform.html`, it will submit to `/mysite/myapp/upload.form`

It then becomes a matter of configuring Spring to handle `"/upload.form"` request accordingly, such as through `@RequestMapping` if you're using annotation-based Spring MVC.  See [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) for more information.